# Bluetooth data transfer between android device and PC through bluetooth adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an requirement here- that i have to send some images and files through my android device to PC via bluetooth adapter .
According to android documentation in order to make connection between two devices via bluetooth ,you need to make one as a client and other as a server.
I can connect between two devices by implementing BluetoothSocket connection between two different devices.
But how will i make my Pc act as a server through code.

how will i acheive that with the help of code.

So, far this is my code for making request as a client via BluetoothSocket

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{
    private  BluetoothSocket mmSocket=null;
                public  static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("6983e974-9696-4547-afc2-143235069a79");
                 @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice

                    BluetoothDevice bluetoothdevice=BluetoothConnection.btAdapter.getRemoteDevice("14:F6:5A:63:0F:8E");
                    try {
                        BluetoothSocket socket=bluetoothdevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ConnectThread.MY_UUID);
                        BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        if(adapter!=null)
                        {
                        adapter.cancelDiscovery();  
                        }

                        if(socket!=null)
                        {

                            socket.connect();
                            Log.i("***Socket Connection Successful**", "Socket Connection Successful");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("***Error**","Socket Connection failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you work with Android, I assume you are familiar with Java. So I looked the Internet for you and found a sample how to make a simple Bluetooth Server:

[Source](http://www.miniware.net/mobile/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22)

Unfortunately it is using another jar for accessing bluetooth capability. But I found more information about it on a blog:

> Bluecove is a JSR-82 implementation.
>   JSR-82 is a java specification for defining APIs for communicating with Bluetooth devices.

[Source of the text above](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/01/08/connecting-to-bluetooth-devices-with-java/)

Reading the Code as Java novice tells me the Steps you have to go for setting up a Bluetotth Server (in Java):

1. Getting your Hardware (getLocalDevice())
2. Make it visible for others, so every bluetooth adapter can find it (setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC))
3. Open your Connection to wait for incoming devices ((StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);)
4. Accept incoming connections and handle them (conn = server.acceptAndOpen();)

So it is like building an own TCP Server via Sockets. I just read it and thought about it. **I did not test it!** So I can not say if this will work properly. But I think that points you into the right way, hopefully.

In addition, I found an article about Bluetooth and java on the  [oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javame/index-140411.html)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to let android handle this if applicable for you scenario.

First check if Bluetooth is available on the device

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (btAdapter == null) {
   // No Bluetooth available on the device
}
```

If it is available we can start an intent and let the android os handle the sending of your files.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File file = new File("<THE PATH TO YOUR FILE>");

sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
//you can also pass a ArrayList<Uri> uriList for multiple files.
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share file"));
```

This will show a new activity which prompts the user to select a bluetooth device. As the dialog will only show paired devices this will either be a precondition.

---

You can initalize a pairing by calling `createBond()` on your `BluetoothDevice`(see here for further detail [createBond() apidoc](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()).

This could look something like this

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothdevice = BluetoothConnection.btAdapter.getRemoteDevice("14:F6:5A:63:0F:8E");
bluetoothdevice.createBond();
```

to trigger the sending create a `BroadcastReceiver` on `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`

```
final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);
       if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            //Trigger the sending via the above mentioned method
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: i have to do with socket connection programatically  ,not with the android bluetooth